# How to edit Symbolic Links in OS X?

Tags: symlink, alias

I had painstakingly gone through and created symlnks to a whole host of files in my system.  I couldn't use aliases because they were failing to be copied with RSync, and also certain apps I use to access my home system remotely over iOS, couldn't handle Aliases but worked fine with symlinks.

Now however I had to change some hard drives around, and my original files are now in a new location.  This of course means all my symlinks have broken.

Aliases deal with this just fine but as stated above, I have to stick with symlinks.  Is there any way to mass-edit these symlinks?  I just need to change the name of the drive in the path.  The old location was for example:

`/Volumes/Old Drive/path/to/file`

the new one is:

`/Volumes/New Drive/path/to/file`

Seems like there should be a workable command line way to do this since they'll all require the same change.  I found at least one utility (Make Symlink) which claims to allow this, but it appears to be many years old and looks abandoned.  I couldn't even manage to decompress the .sit archive it was packed in.

**EDIT:**  I found [this page](http://www.unix.com/showthread.php?t=53319), which suggests that in unix anyway, proper us of `ln` should do the trick, but so far it doesn't appear to do anything - not even output any error message when pointed to a non-existent symlink.

Answer (score 5):

Got it!  Turns out `ln` is the answer after all, but I had an error in my path.

Here is a functional command line for anyone who might need to edit a symlink "in place" in the future:

`ln -f -s /path/to/new/location/of/original /path/to/location/of/broken/symlink/`

Notice that you're not actually pointing all the way to the broken symlink itself, but to the directory that *contains* the broken symlink.  This assumes that the expected name of the symlink, is identical to the original name of the linked item.

This is of course for fixing a single link, but from here I can imagine it wouldn't be overly difficult to script a solution that applied something like this recursively.